# Finding objects between two dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, parse-platform

Okay so I have a parse database with two keys (startedAt) and (endedAt) basically I would like to return all the objects between these two given times. However, I store the times as strings, not dates. I would really like to not have to change them to dates as that would force me to rework code in a lot of other parts of my program. So is it possible to do the following

```
    NSDate *leftDate = leftClassRoomAfterDatePicker.date;
    NSDate *arrivedDate = arrivedBeforeDatePicker.date;


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd hh:mm"];

    NSString *leftDateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:leftDate];
    NSString *arrivedDateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:arrivedDate];

    NSLog(leftDateString);
    NSLog(arrivedDateString);

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"PassData"];
    [query whereKey:@"startTime" greaterThan:leftDate];
    [query whereKey:@"timeArrived" lessThan:arrivedDate];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d objects.", objects.count);
    }];
```

When I run this code I get the following error

The problem is that the strings are not returning the correct value. In my parse database I have a value of startTime:    Dec 08, 18:28
and             endTime:      Dec 08, 18:28

But it still does not work (no objects are returned). I think this is because the greaterthan/lessthan functions will not work on strings like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've converted `leftDate` and `arrivedDate` to `leftDateString` and `arrivedDateString`, but you're still using `leftDate` and `arrivedDate` in your query. I think you meant to write:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"PassData"];
[query whereKey:@"startTime" greaterThan:leftDateString];
[query whereKey:@"timeArrived" lessThan:arrivedDateString];
```

in which case you'd no longer get the error since you'd be comparing string to string.

Although I generally recommend that you store and sort your dates with `NSDate` objects, in this case where your format is in the same descending order of importance as a typical `NSDate` sort of month, day, hour, then minute, i.e. "MM-dd hh:mm", as long as year or seconds don't matter to you and as long as the queried time format matches the database time format, this query should work since `greaterThan` and `lessThan` will compare the string objects alphabetically/numerically.

Comment: I have edited my question. So then do I need to change how the dates are stored in the database? Because I don't think the greaterthan/lessthan will work correctly as it is now

Comment: @user2547771 Good point. Depends on whether greaterThan and lessThan work for string comparisons...

Comment: @user2547771 The docs aren't specific about this so I would try it and see what happens. Check out the last paragraph of my answer to see why it may work.

Comment: I think parse understands NSDate the same way it understands Date in JSSDK, there is no need to convert them to string.

Comment: This worked great! As a future reference to future viewers make sure that you are comparing dates in the same format also!

Comment: @user2547771 Fair enough. I've made the update you suggested for clarity's sake. Glad it worked :)

Comment: @Andy Yeah, but the OP said he's storing the dates as strings in the database and doesn't want to go back and change the PFObjects.

Comment: Bad design and unwillingness to fix it. Can't help it.

Comment: Who me?? Like I said in my answer "I generally recommend that you store and sort your dates with NSDate objects", but Stackoverflow is about answering the OP's question so I explained how, why, and under what circumstances their database design could still work. (Referring to your now edited "poor thing, do you know anything about databases?" comment)

Answer (score 1):

> Error: startTime contains string values but got a date (Code: 102,
>   Version: 1.2.21)

The error clearly indicates that you are comparing two different objects one is string and second one is date. So there are two things you can either convert any one into date or string. So to implement the same in a easy way, you can write one category with function which will convert either into date or string and use that method to perform the comparison.

Comment: My question wasn't very clear. Thank you for your response, I have edited it accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: yes, I have tried it as a string and as a date. it does not return results for either one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess for that to work you have to have `Date` fields in database, then you pass NSDate to `whereKey:` on iOS.